# Combobox ItemTemplate & SelectedValue

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, mvvm-light, windows-8.1-universal

i have modified the item template of my combobox to disable the problem of items looping (Combobox scroll is unlimited , in touche mode )

```
<ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Since that change is made, i can't modify the selectedItem from ViewModel.

Full Combobox :

```
 <ComboBox BorderBrush="#D4D4D4" Margin="312,64,22,142" Grid.Row="1" 

                          ItemsSource="{Binding TypeRemplissageListe,Mode=TwoWay}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                          SelectedValuePath="Value"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTypeRemplissage,Mode=TwoWay}"
                          v:FieldValidationExtensions.Format="NonEmpty" Grid.Column="1"
                           >
                    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
  </ComboBox>
```

ViewModel :

```
 private string _selectedTypeRemplissage;
    public string SelectedTypeRemplissage
    {
        get { return _selectedTypeRemplissage; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedTypeRemplissage != value)
            {
                _selectedTypeRemplissage = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTypeRemplissage");
            }
        }
    }


    SelectedTypeRemplissage = TypeRemplissageListe.ElementAt(0).Name;
```

DataList Class :

```
 public class DataList 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So your code does work when only removing the `<ComboBox.ItemsPanel>` lines?

Comment: yes , everything work fine , the problem is in the specified template, i guess i need a customized Combobox !

Answer (score 0):

Yes the issue is with Itemspanel, since the Itemspanel has Stackpanel in it the virtualization is not enabled hence the selected item is not highlighted.

Change the Stackpanel to Itemsstackpanel and it should work.